# How to see the variables current value of a running matlab process on tmux?

Tags: process, tmux, matlab

I have a `matlab` process in `tmux` which is running for days. Actually I need to see the values of calculated variables till now. I thought that, it is good(if possible) to duplicate the process and then `Ctrl+C` one of them and see the variables values.